# Update "People or Group" and "Hyperlink & Picture" columns using "Build a Dictionary" action

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, people-picker, updatelistitems, dictionary

Using SP Designer 2013 workflow, a list from a Site Collection A is updated by a list in Site Collection B.

I used the below article to achieve this.

https://mysharepointexperiences.wordpress.com/2017/03/18/using-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-updatecreate-item-in-other-site-collection/comment-page-1/#comment-176

However,"People or Group" and "Hyperlink & Picture" columns are not getting updated by the workflow. If I add these column types to "Build a Dictionary" action, the update itself is getting skipped.

How to update "People or Group" and "Hyperlink & Picture" columns  using this method or it is not possible to update these columns types?

Please Note: Updating all other column types are working fine. If i just add a "People or Group" or "Hyperlink & Picture" column to the "Build a Dictionary" action, the workflow skips the updates.

Below is my Build dictionary action for updating a list from a Site Collection A by a list in Site Collection B.

[image]